# NPE when Executing Spark Jobs : Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nullpointerexception, group-by

I keep getting NPE when running a spark job, but I am having null checks on the input :

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 62 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 62.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 83757, ip-172-31-6-49.ec2.internal): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MyUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:90)
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MyUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:90)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MyUtils$.<init>(<console>:90)
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.MyUtils$lzycompute(<console>:79)
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.MyUtils(<console>:79)
    at $line125.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MyUtils$.readResolve(<console>:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1810)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code :

```
   val result =   df.map{
        case r =>
        val id = r.getAs[String]("id")
        val key = r.getAs[String]("key")
        val value = r.getAs[Int]("value")

        (id, Map(key -> value)

    }.reduceByKey((x, y) => x ++ y).map{
          case (k, v) =>
            (k, JacksonUtil.toJson(Data(v)))
        }

result.saveAsTextFile("s3://...")
```

My Config :

```
  spark.driver.cores    30
    spark.driver.memory 200g
    spark.executor.cores    16
    spark.executor.instances    40
    spark.executor.memory   60g
    spark.memory.fraction   0.95
    spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdump

    spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdump
```

Can some one tell if I am doing anything wrong here ? It works fine with smaller data set.  Do I need to change any config ?

Comment: have you tried option,  where ever you are suspecting data could be null ? I suspect operation on null is happening here  x ++ y. But its better to safe guard with option every where and check with `isDefined` method.

Comment: @RamPrasadG Are u suggesting to add if check inside reduce by key ?

Comment: no I think its not possible. but where ever you are getting data values.

Comment: Error message says this happens in line 90 - can you point us to that line?

Comment: the line `(id, Map(key -> value)` should be `(id, Map(key -> value))`